# LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing document loaders from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of lang

Tags: python, pip, openai-api, langchain, chromadb

Im getting below warning and im able to reinstall pip but still it gives below warning.
Error:
.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/**init**.py:36: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing document loaders from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

```
`from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader`.

To install langchain-community run `pip install -U langchain-community`.
  warnings.warn(
/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/__init__.py:36: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing document loaders from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

`from langchain_community.document_loaders import TextLoader`.

To install langchain-community run `pip install -U langchain-community`.
  warnings.warn(
/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/embeddings/__init__.py:29: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing embeddings from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

`from langchain_community.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings`.

To install langchain-community run `pip install -U langchain-community`.
  warnings.warn(
/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/llms/__init__.py:548: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing LLMs from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

`from langchain_community.llms import OpenAI`.

To install langchain-community run `pip install -U langchain-community`.
  warnings.warn(
/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/__init__.py:35: LangChainDeprecationWarning: Importing vector stores from langchain is deprecated. Importing from langchain will no longer be supported as of langchain==0.2.0. Please import from langchain-community instead:

`from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma`.

To install langchain-community run `pip install -U langchain-community`.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 81, in __init__
    import chromadb
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import chromadb.config
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/chromadb/config.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pydantic import BaseSettings
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/__init__.py", line 374, in __getattr__
    return _getattr_migration(attr_name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pydantic/_migration.py", line 296, in wrapper
    raise PydanticImportError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/u/import-error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bata/balm1fxr/OpenAI/chatgpt-retrieval-main/chatgpt.py", line 35, in <module>
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/indexes/vectorstore.py", line 84, in from_loaders
    return self.from_documents(docs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain/indexes/vectorstore.py", line 89, in from_documents
    vectorstore = self.vectorstore_cls.from_documents(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 778, in from_documents
    return cls.from_texts(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 714, in from_texts
    chroma_collection = cls(
                        ^^^^
  File "/home/balm1fxr/.localpython/lib/python3.12/site-packages/langchain_community/vectorstores/chroma.py", line 84, in __init__
    raise ImportError(
**ImportError: Could not import chromadb python package. Please install it with `pip install chromadb`**

**Chatgp.py code** 

import os
import sys

import openai
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain, RetrievalQA
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader, TextLoader
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.indexes.vectorstore import VectorStoreIndexWrapper
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

import constants

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = constants.APIKEY

PERSIST = False

query = None
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  query = sys.argv[1]

if PERSIST and os.path.exists("persist"):
  print("Reusing index...\n")
  vectorstore = Chroma(persist_directory="persist", embedding_function=OpenAIEmbeddings())
  index = VectorStoreIndexWrapper(vectorstore=vectorstore)
else:
  #loader = TextLoader("data/data.txt") # Use this line if you only need data.txt
  loader = DirectoryLoader("data/")
  if PERSIST:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator(vectorstore_kwargs={"persist_directory":"persist"}).from_loaders([loader])
  else:
    index = VectorstoreIndexCreator().from_loaders([loader])

chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
  llm=ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo"),
  retriever=index.vectorstore.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1}),
)

chat_history = []
while True:
  if not query:
    query = input("Prompt: ")
  if query in ['quit', 'q', 'exit']:
    sys.exit()
  result = chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
  print(result['answer'])

  chat_history.append((query, result['answer']))
  query = None
```

Comment: Did you try what the warning said?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same deprecation warning, but
"from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI" worked.
There's a bug logged in the langchain that the team is looking at.
https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-py/issues/8212